# How to remove unseen module from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, pinterest

I am new to android studio and working on pinterest development kit (PDK) for sharing purpose,I, have added pdk as a module to my main project,But i cant see it in my project structure,Or i havent declared it in build.gradle as well,So i want to use pdk or want to remove it already addeda safe way.

Answer (score 0):

Try File -->Project Structure --> Module and then remove it or you can add a dependencies clicking app --> Dependencies and hit the plus button to add the module to your project.